# How to write a simple C# script to copy file to directory one level up?

Tags: c#, file, copy, move

Trying to write a simple C# script to copy file to directory one level up. Here is what I have, but it is sending an error,

> "Script.OnActivate()" not all code paths return a value.

and my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Globalization;

    class Script : CopyFile {

        public static bool OnActivate() {
            CopyDataFile("script/file.js", "../file.js");
        }

    }
```

### SOLVED!

```
using System;
using System.IO;

class Script : CopyFile {

    public static void OnActivate() {
        FileInfo myFile = new FileInfo("script/file.js"); 
        myFile.CopyTo(myFile.Directory.Parent.FullName + "\\" + myFile.Name); 
    }

}
```

This moves file.js into the directory one level up from "script/"

Comment: I think the first parameter should be the full path as well as the second one...

Comment: @RobinVanPersi That's not what the error is about.

Comment: i just noticed that you need to change "bool" to void... or you can add return true in the end of the function...

Comment: I changed "bool" to "void" and now I get this error: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: there is a problem in your "CopyDataFile" function you need to provide more codes... and where the exception is actually happening?

Comment: @Robin: please rephrase your question. I think you are ansing a question in which this is the answer: full error is as follows: `System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object at Nexus.Client.ModManagement.Scripting.CSharpScript.ScriptRunner.Execute(Byte[]p_bteScript)` within Nexus Mod Manager

Comment: @user1158415, the `NullReferenceException` appears to be coming from inside `CopyDataFile`, but you haven't posted the code for `CopyDataFile` so we can't help you troubleshoot the problem.

Comment: @user1158415, then I think there is a problem from the paths you provided in CopyDataFile... you need to provide the correct full paths and especially for the first parameter..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error occurs because you do not return a `bool`

```
   public static bool OnActivate() {
        CopyDataFile("script/file.js", "../file.js");
        return true;
    }
```

If you dont want to return something change you method to return `void`, do the following

```
   public static void OnActivate() {
        CopyDataFile("script/file.js", "../file.js");
    }
```

> **MSDN** The void operator evaluates its expression, and returns undefined. It is most useful in situations where you want an expression evaluated but do not want the results visible to the remainder of the script.

Comment: *If you dont want to return something* then don't `return true` in a `void` function...

Comment: I have updated my answer in the same moment you wrote your comment. You are right. But my answer is already updated. Thanks!

Comment: I changed "bool" to "void" and now I get this error:
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: Not enough information. I think you should provide more source code. When did this happen ?

Comment: okay full error is as follows: `System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object at Nexus.Client.ModManagement.Scripting.CSharpScript.ScriptRunner.Execute(Byte[]p_bteScript)` within Nexus Mod Manager

Comment: I mean you should post more sourcecode. The exception message does not help in this case

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7133/discussion-between-dknaack-and-user1158415)

Comment: In the very long chat the question was answered. Thank you dknaack! I updated the question with the answer.

Answer (score 3):

The description is as it is described. You need to change your OnActive to be void, or return a boolean (ie. If CopyDataFile returns a boolean, then return CopyDataFile(...))